# How many calls can a PHP Nominatim API respond to each second?

Tags: php, linux, amazon-ec2, openstreetmap, nominatim

I have setup a PHP Nominatim API on an Amazon R3 Linux instance. (15GB ram 2VCPU etc. (its a pretty fast computer))

Approximately how many API calls per second can I expect it to respond to?

I am planning on making 40 million reverse geocode API calls in total and need to know how many times to call it each second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While not knowing exact numbers, I can only give you a wild guess based on looking on the stats of the public Nominatim server running on osm.org: Currently, it handles about [6k reverse geocoding requests per minute (100 per second)](http://munin.osm.org/openstreetmap/poldi.openstreetmap/nominatim_requests.html) while running on pretty [powerful hardware](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Servers/poldi) (24 cores, 96GB RAM). Maybe you can get an idea what the performance of your machine will be.

Comment: Cool thank you that is very helpful!! So I think about 1/6th. I.e 16 requests per second is my upper limit. :)

Comment: where did you get 24 cores? Doesn't it say 2x quad cores?